# Stratified Random Sampling by ID in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, random, sampling

I've been playing around with the Random Points tool in QGIS to realize stratified random sampling, but I'm running into a problem where I want my strata to be based on a polygon ID, not each individual polygon.  In other words: I may have multiple non-contiguous polygons that all represent a single strata, where I want a TOTAL of (e.g.) 10 points randomly distributed among the disconnected polygons, not 10 per polygon.  Is there any way to do this?  Would a multi-part polygon work, for this?

Comment: Did you tried points in polygon option>?

Answer (score 2):

Using a multi-part polygon does work. Below, a multi-part (blue) and single polygon:
[image: Multi-part polygon (blue) and single (white)]

Using the random points tool and 20 points per polygon, 20 points are distributed amongst all three blue parts of the first polygon:
[image]